# Database Schema

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, mysqli

I have create an application for my client. They are wanting to be able to join 2 or more products together.

Table turbo_connections, has 3 columns `primary_id`, `partner_id` and `verified`.

What would be the best way to use this?

1. When you go to find stock loop through the table and find all of the primary_id's of what the current turbo is linked to and then keep searching until there is no more left to find.
2. When going to add a link between the 2 products get all the other connections of the partner_id and primary_id already and add them to each other so makes display stock easier because all data will be there.

Or if you have an idea I am all up for learning.

Comment: Welcome to stack, you may want to take a moment to familiarize yourself with our [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  This portion of the stack community is CODE based.  Meaning we generally assist in SPECIFIC code questions.  For example: I've tried to do the following: `Select * from table where 1==@variable` and it's not working what am I doing wrong?  Schema and design related questions may be better suited at a partner site: programmers.stackexchange.com - Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development. YOu may get better luck there.

Comment: @xQbert - this might be on topic for Programmers, but can I suggest you re-familiarise yourself with [our FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq). We have updated it fairly recently.

Comment: What have you tried? What's unsatisfying about the options you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a join.  It sounds like you're not familiar with them.

There's lots of tutorials on the web, such as this one:  [SQL Joins Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

What you'd want to do is join the turbo_connections table with the products table. As a contrived example:

```
select * from turbo_connections t join products p on t.primary_id = p.primary_id
```

That will give you the list of products and turbo_connections that have matching primary_id's.

If you want to edit your post with more details about your tables and what the desired output should be, we can suggest the proper joins necessary.

Comment: Hey, I already have the products table that selects them. What is I wanted to know is what would be easier.

When adding a connection add the connection but then select all the connections the connection already had and insert them as well (Because if one product matches then all the products that are on the one you are adding as a match it will need to add the others) OR when selecting the turbo connection find what the turbo is linked to and then find what there linked to but could go on for a while.

Comment: You're going to have to give more detail.  That doesn't make any sense to someone not familiar with your data.